# Create copies of primitives a number of times along a given or random length between two primitives

Tags: modeling

Thanks for the reply but I’m not sure that the solution offered works as I wanted. I have included a workflow to clarify what can be done easily on Sketchup requiring no calculations. This is what I would like to do in Blender. I’m sure It would be a really good addition to the Array modifier and I’m sure relatively easy to code.[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "no calculations"?

Comment: Up until now the vast majority of those that I asked about this told me to use math calculations to place prims accordingly. I was just trying to make the point that SketchUp example was a simple drag to a random location. I had seen a Vid of something similar by somebody called Fabio "Advanced Array Modifier" but couldnt track down if it had been implemented - so I knew it could be done.

Comment: The script provided was good, so the calculation was done for you.   You got very lucky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NEW**

I rewrote this script today, it is available at: [github.com/zeffii/B3D_PrimitiveRepeat](https://github.com/zeffii/B3D_PrimitiveRepeat)

Similar Features but simpler code and UI.

Changes:

- now can access operator properties from Tools or F6 (I prefer F6)
- has 3 main modes

  - linear: precise segments between two linked duplicates
  - deviate: similar to linear but with a randomization *seed + amplitude*
  - random: random locations between the two linked duplicates.
- has 2 interpolation modes

  - matrix interpolation (all transforms)
  - vector interpolation (locations)
- adds an empty and parents the generated objects to it. This allows you to quickly delete them using *Outliner-Delete Hierarchy* with their Empty selected.

---

**OLD**

Here's [an attempt at such a script](https://gist.github.com/zeffii/5283937b8e0995207e25). It is intended to inspire you to write your own addons / macros to customize your Blender experience. Not everyone understands why certain functionality is handy.

But it's not exactly the same behaviour as SketchUp (ie you don't need to snap the primitive to the other primitive first)

- Select Two objects which use the same mesh. (Objects duplicated using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> share a mesh, and are called "Linked Duplicates")
- Trigger the addon:

  - press Left Bracket / Right Bracket to increase decrease the number of repeated objects
  - press Ctrl + Up/Down to change the seed value for the random location
  - Enter or Esc to finish up, or click outside of the 3dview.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

- The array modifier can repeat an object with additional space.
- The array modifier with Fit Length below.
  [image]

  - The array modifier can repeat object along a curve.  Curves can be straight lines as well.  Fit Curve below.

[image]

- The array modifier is dynamic or can be applied for static placement.
- Perhaps the array modifier is more powerful than that other feature in that other software.
- Particle systems can also repeat geometry.