# How do I divide equally copies by the distance between two objects

Tags: modeling

Sorry for my bad English, I'm very new to Blender, how do i divide equally copies by the distance between two objects like the Multiply and Divide features in Google SketchUp to copy objects over large spaces, please take a look in the photo showing my problem

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30944/create-copies-of-primitives-a-number-of-times-along-a-given-or-random-length-bet

Answer (score 1):

A solution is the Array Modifier. Found here.

[image]